# .NET library for Microsoft Office XML format

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Is there any library that can write excel files in [Microsoft Office XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) ? I can't use MS Interop Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx) , ECMA Office Open XML ("Open XML") is an international, open standard for word-processing documents, presentations, and spreadsheets that can be freely implemented by multiple applications on multiple platforms,[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx).

Comment: Is it necessary to install the SDK also on the clients computer ?

Answer (score 2):

I've used [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) in a few of my projects with no issues at. I've used it in Web and Desktop based applications. The API is pretty easy to pick up and run with it. With it I've been able to generate new documents, read and edit existing,manipulate the fortmatting. It even supports using a [LINQ syntax](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LinqExample) which is pretty fun.. at least I think so :)

It's [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) licensed so you can use it in commercial and non-commercial projects.